# Color command not working using system() function in c

Tags: c, system, dos

System command is used to execute the dos shell commands using the c program asif they were executed directly on command prompt itself.

color command working on the dos shell when applied directly but fails when used by the system() function.

Comment: `system` is the wrong function for changing the console's colours. Use [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: `color` is internal to `dos`, so I imagine when `system` exits, the settings disappear (similar to how `system("cd ...")` wouldn't work)

Comment: What is the goal?  How should color values be distinguishable within a C program?

Comment: @abiessu I imagine the goal is to have different-colored text output to the command prompt window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `COLOR` is an internal command and not a program, the `system()` function (normally) cannot recognize it.

However, you can try by using the `CMD` program, with parameter `/K`, in this way:

```
    system("CMD.EXE /K COLOR 63 ");
```